# What is correct SELECT statment to JOIN this tables

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL problem:

```
Mysql Database xyz 

Table 1
-----------------------
Email              Name

1.john@doe.com     john 
-----------------------

Table 2 

-----------------------
Email              Color

1.john@doe.com     red 
2.john@doe.com     orange 
3.john@doe.com     blue 
-----------------------
```

What is the correct way to do a query with:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE table1.email ='john doe'
```

so i get mysql query result

```
[john@doe.com,john,red,orange,blue]
```

my bad solution :

```
 SELECT Name ,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Color) As Colors FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Email = 'john@doe.com') 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Table1.Email = 'john@doe.com';
```

Comment: `SELECT email,color FROM table2` then handle the display logic in application code.

Comment: NO JOIN ,or LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the colors in a comma-separated column.

Comment: Well yeah, you need the join too - but there's no John Doe in table1

Comment: this is not good : SELECT Name ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Color) As Colors FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.email = 'john@doe.com') FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.email = 'john@doe.com';

Comment: To my way of thinking, GROUP_CONCAT serves (almost) no useful purpose - but whatever rocks your boat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works, but a better way is with a join.

```
SELECT t1.email, t1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.color) AS colors
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.email = t2.email
WHERE t1.email = 'john@doe.com';
```

This is better because you only have to specify the email you're looking for in one place. And if you replace the `WHERE` clause with `GROUP BY t1.email` you get everyone.

Comment: You only need that if you want more than one user.